# Angularjs - check if i am typing in input and toggle loader icon

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, focus

i'm new in angularjs and i'm trying to change an icon when i'm typing in a input box. Actually i'm able to detect if i have the focus in this way:

```
 $scope.loading = false;
 $scope.focused = function() {
        console.log("got focus");
        $scope.loading = true;
    }
    $scope.blurred = function() {
        console.log("lost focus");
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
```

and in the html:

```
<i data-ng-if="!loading" class="uk-icon-search"></i>
                    <i data-ng-if="loading" class="uk-icon-spinner uk-icon-spin"></i>
                    <input ng-focus="focused()" ng-blur="blurred()" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
```

in this way if the loading variable is true i can change the icon when i click on the input.. But i would show the spinner icon when i'm starting typing and when i click "Enter" button change icon again. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Look into [ngKeypress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

Answer (score 1):

Simple view example

```
<div ng-controller="hey">
      <input type="text" ng-model="key" ng-keypress="whenTyping($event)" ng-blur="whenNotTyping($event)"/>  
      <img src="/path/to/img.png" ng-show="typing"/>
      <img src="/path/to/img.png" ng-show="!typing"/>
</div>
```

Simple controller example

```
.controller('hey', function ($scope, $log) {

   $scope.whenTyping = function (event) {
     //the model you typing
     $log.info($scope.key);
     //the event typing
     $log.info(event);
    //you are typing hide img
    $scope.typing = true;
   } 

   $scope.whenNotTyping = function (event) {
     //the model you typed before
     $log.info($scope.key);
     //the event on blur
     $log.info(event);
    //you are not typing hide img
    $scope.typing = false;
   } 
});
```

Anyway, i would suggest a directive other than a controller for what you need.

Comment: is it possible that this way make all slower when i typing?

Comment: @End.Game actually should not, show what you tried on a plunkr or jsfiddle for example i may help better ;)